# How to build a dynamic table with dependent column values - like on click of country all states should come from array or db

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to build a table with dependent values like - if I click on the country then all states should show with the highlighted country. If states are more which is not fit in the column vertically then add a scroll to state column vertically.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Select</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#country1').click(function() {
           $('.hideit').toggle("slide");
         });
     });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
     .container {
     display: table;
     border-collapse:collapse
     }
     .column {
     display:table-row;
     border: 1px solid black;
     }
     .cell {
     display: table-cell;
     border-collapse:collapse
     width: 120px;
     height: 20px;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     }
  </style>
  <div class="container">
     <div class="cell">
        <div class="column"><a href="#" id="country1" >country1</a></div>
        <div class="column">country2</div>
        <div class="column">country3</div>
     </div>
     <div class="cell hideit">
        <div class="column">state1</div>
        <div class="column">state2</div>
        <div class="column">state3</div>
     </div>
     <div class="cell ScrollStyle">
        <div class="column">city1</div>
        <div class="column">city2</div>
        <div class="column">city2</div>
        <div class="column">city3</div>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

if I click on the country then all states should show with the highlighted country. If states are more which is not fit in the column vertically then add a scroll to state column vertically.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Select</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            //country Array to make country list
            var country = ["INDIA","USA","AUS"];
            for(var i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {
                var countryName = country[i];
                var $li = $("<li><a href='#'>"+ countryName +"</a></li>");      
                $("#countryLinkList").append($li);  
                //$("li:first-child").addClass('active');
            }

            //onclick of any country
            $('.countryList li').click(function() { 
                $(this).closest('ul').find('.active').removeClass();
                $(this).addClass('active');
                //$(".cityliclass li").removeClass();
                $(".cityliclass").empty();
                //var countryClicked = $("a",this).attr('href'); 
                var countryClicked =  $(this).text();
                $("#div2").addClass('child');
                $("#div3").removeClass('child');    //remove div 3 on click of country click to make country and state div in center.
                $("#stateHidden").val("");          //make state hidden value null so city hides on click of country.

                //country state array
                var countryState = { 
                    "INDIA": ["KA", "MP", "TN"],
                    "USA": ["WA", "NY", "CO"],
                    "AUS": ["SY","AD","SYD"]
                };

                $("#stateLinkList").empty();
                $("#stateLinkList").append("<h4>State</h4>");
                for (countryName in countryState){
                    if(countryName === countryClicked){
                        for (stateNameOfCountry in countryState[countryName]) { 
                            var stateName = countryState[countryName][stateNameOfCountry];
                            var $stateLi = $("<li><a href='#'>"+ stateName +"</a></li>");                       
                            $("#stateLinkList").append($stateLi); 
                            //$(".liclass li:first-child").addClass('active');
                        }   
                    }
                }
            });

            //onclick of any state
            $('.stateList').on('click','li a', function(){  
                $(this).closest('ul').find('.active').removeClass();
                $(this).closest('ul li').addClass('active');
                $("#div3").addClass('child');

                var stateClicked =  $(this).text();
                var stateHidden = $("#stateHidden").val(stateClicked);

                //state city array
                var stateCity = { 
                    "KA": ["Banglore", "Mysore", "Manglore"],
                    "MP": ["Bhopal", "Satna", "Indore"],
                    "TN": ["Chennai", "Coimbatore", "Hosur"],
                    "WA": ["Albion", "Conconully", "Fairfield"],
                    "NY": ["Hudson", "Kingston", "Lockport "],
                    "CO": ["Springfield", "Rico", "Denver"],
                    "SY": ["Sydney","Adiled","Sydney city"],
                    "AD": ["Perth","Karratha","Albany"],
                    "SYD": ["Caboolture","Armidale","Lithgow"]
                };

                $("#cityLinkList").empty();
                $("#cityLinkList").append("<h4>City</h4>");
                for (stateNameList in stateCity){ 
                    if(stateNameList === stateClicked){
                        for (cityNameOfState in stateCity[stateNameList]) { 
                            var cityName = stateCity[stateNameList][cityNameOfState];
                            var $cityLi = $("<li><a href='#'>"+ cityName +"</a></li>");                         
                            $("#cityLinkList").append($cityLi); 
                            //$(".cityliclass li:first-child").addClass('active');
                        }
                    }   
                }

            });

            //onclick of any state
            $('.cityList').on('click','li a', function(){
                $(this).closest('ul').find('.active').removeClass();
                $(this).closest('ul li').addClass('active');

                var cityClicked =  $(this).text();
                alert("hello " + cityClicked);
            });

        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style type="text/css">
            .nav-sidebar {
                background-color: #f5f5f5;
                margin-right: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
                margin-left: 5px;
            }
            .nav-sidebar  > li > a {
                padding-right: 20px;
                padding-left: 20px;
            }
            .nav.nav-sidebar   > li.active > a {
                color: #fff;
                background-color: #1a95ed;
            }
            .floatDiv{
                float: left; 
                width:  33%;
            }
            .addScrollBarvertically{ 
                overflow-y: auto;
                height: 100px;
            }
            .parent {
                width: 90%;
                height: 90%;
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                top:20px;
                margin: auto;

                text-align: center;
            }
            .child  {
              display: inline-block;
              width: 30%;
              height: 90%;  
              overflow: auto;   
              margin: 0 auto !important;
              text-align: left;
            }
            .child ul h4{
                text-align: left;
                color: solid black;
                margin-right: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                /*margin-left: 5px;
                padding-right: 20px;
                background-color: #1a95ed;
                */
                padding-left: 20px;
            }
        </style>

        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child">
                <ul class="countryList nav nav-sidebar" id="countryLinkList"><h4>Country</h4></ul>
            </div>
            <div id="div2">
                <input type="hidden" name="stateHidden" id="stateHidden">
                <ul class="stateList nav nav-sidebar liclass" id="stateLinkList"></ul>
            </div >
            <div id="div3">
                <ul class="cityList nav nav-sidebar cityliclass" id="cityLinkList"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```